# How to deactivate JLine for Jython interactive interpreter session?

Tags: jython, readline

Jython 2.5 comes with JLine per default.

I would prefer to use the interactive interpreter with [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/). It seems that rlwrap is not working if JLine is active.

In Scala I would use `rlwrap scala -Xnojline`.

Is there a similar option for Jython to deactivate JLine?

Comment: Removed the "scala" tag, as the question is not related to Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the jython property python.console to
org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.  This was the default in Jython
2.2 and is a simple history-less console.  You can set this property via the command line like:

jython -Dpython.console=org.python.util.InteractiveConsole

or change the property in your local registry.  See
http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#the-jython-registry

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works:
'rlwrap jython -Dpython.console=org.python.util.InteractiveConsole'. This also works: 'rlwrap jython -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal'.
Answers on 'jython-users' mailing list: http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c177f7ec00907180005i207eaf3cte639dbf574cdedcb%40mail.gmail.com%3e